# how to line up the boxes

Tags: html, css

I was making four boxes that will each be linked to other links using  tag but the last box ("Coming Soon" box) would not line up together with other boxes. I think it is because of the text and the padding within the last box but I have no clue how to fix it.

HTML code:

```
<div class = "rack">
    <div class = "reviews">
        <a class = "box review1" href= "queen.html">
            <p class = "title">Queen's Gambit</p>
        </a>

        <a class = "box review2" href= "good.html">
            <p class = "title">The Good Place</p>
        </a>

        <a class = "box review3" href= "brookyln.html">
            <p class = "title">Brookyln 99</p>
        </a>

        <a class = "box review4" href= "#">
            <p id = "coming-soon">Coming Soon</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.rack {
    padding-top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.reviews a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


.box:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px #AF060F;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 20px;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.review1 {
    background-image: url(../images/queen.JPG);
}

.review2 {
    background-image: url(../images/good.JPG);
}

.review3 {
    background-image: url(../images/brookyln.JPG);
}

.review4 {
    background-color: grey;
}

.review4 #coming-soon {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0;
}

.title {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 220px 0 0 10px;
}
```

And it keeps coming out like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89ucQ.png)

I have only been learning HTML/CSS for few weeks, so it is really challenging for me.
If any of you have ideas on how to fix this please tell me.

Comment: Try flex in CSS, it will make things easy for you to align horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Hello @cheesetart_lover and welcome to stack overflow. Just create an image for the Coming Soon box. instead of making the title larger.

Answer (score 0):

Hello so you did not close the `div` with a `class` of reviews,
also you give the `divs` with the `p` tags in them a background image
you could better put a [`image tag`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) next to the `p` tag
this might help.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the padding in the under the id of comming-soon is messed up.

```
<div class = "rack">
    <div class = "reviews">
        <a class = "box review1" href= "queen.html">
            <p class = "title">Queen's Gambit</p>
        </a>

        <a class = "box review2" href= "good.html">
            <p class = "title">The Good Place</p>
        </a>

        <a class = "box review3" href= "brookyln.html">
            <p class = "title">Brookyln 99</p>
        </a>
        
          <a class = "box review4" href= "#">
            <p class = "title">Coming Soon<</p>
        </a>
        <a class = "box review4" href= "#">
            <p id = "coming-soon">Coming Soon</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.rack {
    padding-top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
}

.reviews a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


.box:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px #AF060F;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 20px;

 
}

.review1 {
    background-image: url(../images/queen.JPG);
}

.review2 {
    background-image: url(../images/good.JPG);
}

.review3 {
    background-image: url(../images/brookyln.JPG);
}

.review4 {
    background-color: grey;
}

.review4 #coming-soon {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 240px 0 0 10px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0;
}

.title {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 220px 0 0 10px;
}
```

I think this might work try it out.
I think its better to use flex which is an interesting property which can be used to solve like the problems